# Calculation doesn't work - flex

Tags: apache-flex, function, flash-builder

I have made a function to calculate a totalprice but it doenst seem to work. The function is made to get 2 datafields from a arraycollection with these the two datafields I want to be able to calculate.

```
        [Bindable]public var total:Number=0;
        private function gridClickEvent(event:ListEvent):void {             
            var quantity:Number=acCart[event.columnIndex].quantity;
            var price:Number=acCart[event.columnIndex].price;
            total += quantity * price;

        }
```

My calculated total will be shown in a label

```
<s:Label id="prijs" text="{total}" />
```

What I want is to calculate a total price. I have an arraycollection with 3 fielddata's (Nameproduct, quantity and price). In a function I want to pull the data "quantity" and the data "price" out of the arraycollection so that I calculate a "totalprice".

At the moment the function i wrote is not working. I don't recieve any data.

Comment: Can you tell us what doesn't work?  What values are you receiving and what values did you expect to receive?  Have you stepped through the code?  What are the values of quantity and price before the calculation is made?  What are the data types of acCart.quantity and acCart.price? What is acCart?  What is the value of event.rowIndex?  I'd guess something is wrong w/ your cast from [unknown data type] to Number.

Comment: What I want is to calculate a total price. I have an arraycollection with 3 fielddata's (Nameproduct, quantity and price). In a function I want to pull the data "quantity" and the data "price" out of the arraycollection so that I calculate a "totalprice".

At the moment the function i wrote is not working. I don't recieve any data.

Comment: acCart is the arraycollection with 3 fielddata's

Comment: Can you tell us what doesn't work?  You don't receive any data where?  In event.rowIndex?  Or acCart[rowIndex].quantity?  Are quantity and price strings? If not; you don't have to run parseFloat on them.

Comment: It doesnt make the calculation my total stays at 0. I don't receive the data from acCart[rowIndex].quantity and acCart[rowIndex].price. I already removed the parsefloats because de data's are numbers not string. Still not working though

Comment: Have you stepped through the code; as others have suggested?  At this point, I think a runnable sample may be necessary because something is clearly amiss.

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting a total of the ArrayCollection, since you're only adding the row that was clicked. Also, are you aware that if you keep clicking that one row, you'd add its values repeatedly to the total? That might be what you're after, but that doesn't seem to be what your question suggests.

Answer (score 2):

It's `total+=` not `total=+`. You have a syntax error in the operator.

Comment: I have changed it to += but the it still doenst work. The label always shows 0

Comment: Have you checked the values coming/used in?

Answer (score 2):

Do some debugging:

```
private function gridClickEvent(event:ListEvent):void {

    //see if getting expected values 
    trace(event.rowIndex);
    trace(acCart[event.rowIndex].quantity);
    trace(acCart[event.rowIndex].price);

    var quantity:Number=parseFloat(acCart[event.rowIndex].quantity);
    var price:Number=parseFloat(acCart[event.rowIndex].price);
    total += quantity * price;
}
```

Comment: Oke I have debugged my project. And the debugger can't trace any values.

Comment: -1.  While performing debugging is good advice; it does not do anything to answer the question.

Comment: -1 in order to provide an answer one must understand the problem. If the binding is not working, the values must be the cause. To get an idea if the values are undefined, NaN or whatever, debugging helps finding the answer.

Comment: If the traces are not working, please fire up alerts (and get the Flash content debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
private function gridClickEvent(event:ListEvent):void {
    .... // your math here

    trace("old total = "+ total);
    total += quantity * price;
    trace("new total = "+ total);

    // forget about binding and manually set the property
    prijs.text = total.toString();
}
```

Binding sometimes is crazy in flex, and even if you/I understand the mechanism of Binding perfectly it may still be the chance that the binding is not working or the values are set N times instead of just once (case of several MVC frameworks out there).

For this reason I hate binding, and I am reserved in using it.

PS: what would your trace output be ? (please "debug",  not run, to get console output)